# Trying to show partial page but for a specific object, so need to pass parameter with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a list of Feedback objects im showing in a partial with a navbar to the right. I want to click 'Show Feedback' to show a specific feedback, still with the navbar to the right. Right now it opens a new page. I want to do all of this with Ajax, so i need to call ajax with a parameter of feedbackId

```
$("#getFeedbackModal").click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/AdminPanel/FeedbackModal/',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#loadResults').html(data);

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
            alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

this is the ajax code. the #loadResults is my navbar ect. my AdminPanel method FeedbackModal takes a feedback ID, it looks like this.

```
  [HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult FeedbackModal(string feedbackId)
        {
            var model = GenerateFeedbackViewModel(feedbackId);
            //for partial view    

            return PartialView("_FeedbackModal",model);
        }
```

Here is the _Feedback partial view where i show a list of feedback, each with a unique id.

```
<tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr class="even pointer">
                                    <td class="a-center ">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="table_records">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy.FirstName)</td>
                                    <td class="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy.Email)</td>
                                    <td class="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.ReportaProblemType.Name)</td>
                                    <td class="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedAt)</td>
                                    <td class="">Not replied yet**</td>
                                    @*<td class=""><button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("FeedbackModal","AdminPanel", new { feedbackId = item.Id })'" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin: 0;">View</button></td>*@
                                    <td>
                                        <a id="getFeedbackModal" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                            Feedback
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
```

The button that is commented out is how i have done it so far, but it doesnt keep the navbar(#loadResults) thing, it takes me to a new page instead.
I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mix Razor and jquery functionality. Since you are  using jquery, better try the following approach.

- In _Feedback partial view, remove onclick event, and add the feedback id to the parent tr as data attribute.

  ```
  <tr class="even pointer" data-feedback-id="item.Id">
  ```
- change the click method as

  ```
  $("#getFeedbackModal").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var feedbackId = $(e.currentTarget).closest('tr').data('feedbackId');
       $.ajax({
           url: '/AdminPanel/FeedbackModal/?feedbackId='+feedbackId,
           type: 'GET',
           success: function (data) {
               $('#loadResults').html(data);
           },
           error: function (xhr, status, error) {
               var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
               alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
           }
     });    
  }
  ```

Comment: hi ! now it works for the first in the list. But the rest do nothing when feedback is pressed. :/ @Adersh

Comment: In that case, add a class property for element with id 'getFeedbackModal', and subscribe click event for that class

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
e.preventDefault();
```

before your ajax call. That will prevent you from navigating to the `/AdminPanel/FeedbackModal/` while the backend code is executing.

I hope that fixes the issue for you.